# migrating email, folder structure?

Tags: email, web-hosting, migration, pop3, webmail

I am currently trying to move a client from one web host to another.  They have been using webmail (smartermail) on old host.  They have folder set up for organizing their mail.

How would I got about migrating this client?  I can fairly easily get the mail over.. but it wont retain folder structure. There is an option in the new webmail client to add an external account which just pulls the pop mail to a single folder.

Any solutions here? or is the client.. sol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention having IMAP access to the mail stores, but if you do, you could look into [imapsync](http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync/). I've used this many times in the past to move mail around. This will copy both the folder structure as well as the messages themselves. One really nice thing is that it works similar to rsync, meaning that you can run the sync one initial time a few days before the cutover - this will copy the vast majority of the mail. Then run it again right before the cutover and it'll just copy the new items that have arrived since the initial sync.

Comment: looks like imapsync is linux based, and im not familiar with linux.  i do have full access to the old web hosting.  we own the equipment in a co-lo.  but i do not have full access on the new equipment, though i can probably have support help me.

Answer (score 0):

what about tar the folder and scp it to the next host?